# How to get both sender and receiver name from a different table

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to make a simple Message class for PHP. My `messages` table structure is as follows:

`id, sender_id, receiver_id, msg, date`

I want to get sender and receiver username from `users` table. How can I do it in a single query?

Example output I expect:

`sender, sender_id, receiver, receiver_id, msg, date`

Comment: This question is very clear if you are in sql

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you must join messages with users two times to get the results you want. try the following query:

```
select distinct sender.username as senderName, sender.user_id as sender_id,
                receiver.username as receiverName, receiver.user_id as receiver_id, 
                msg.msg_body, msg.date 
from messages msg inner join users sender on msg.sender_id = sender.id
                  inner join users receiver on msg.receiver_id = receiver.id
```

Comment: I didn't understand a thing from your answer.

Comment: you must join messages and users tables two times to get sender and receiver names. To use a table in a query more than one times, you must use alias names for each one as  users sender in which sender is a copy of table users (Actually it is a new pointer/iterator not a copy).

Comment: I did something but it returns each record twice

Comment: simply add distinct to your select (select distinct sender, sender_id, receiver, receiver_id, msg, date)

Comment: Could you send a full example and edit your answer?

Comment: have you done with this???

Comment: replace WHERE with ON and query works just fine.